# Problem with sysdate in query with myBatis?

Tags: plsql, mybatis

I have a query similar to this one, when i execute in the sql/developer it works perfectly, it checks the sysdate correctly:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM TB_ADT_AEAT_ESTADOS
    WHERE F_MODIF < SYSDATE-5/1440;
```

But when i launch my code and the same query is executed in myBatis, the query works but doesn´t check correctly the sysdate-x/1440 operation, i pass the X parameter like an Integer in the mapper:

```
<select id="xxx" resultMap="xxx">
    SELECT *
    FROM TB_ADT_AEAT_ESTADOS
    WHERE F_MODIF < SYSDATE-#{paramIpass}/1440
</select>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, already figured it out. The query is more complex with multiply join and union and in the Constants i passed duplicate values and the result i needed to check date was checked but the next union query still was giving me he results without checking date.

Sorry is someone lost his time trying to see something similar, thank you again, my mistake.